# Perl Moose, How to initialize a instance attribute that is Hash

Tags: perl, moose

What I am tring to do is the following:

I am writing a perl Moose Class and I want ot have a class attribute that is an Hash and is initialized to default values upon building.

My attempt:

```
has sweep_prop_configuration => (
    is=>'rw',
    isa => 'Hash',
    reader => 'sweep_prop_configuration',
    writer => '_sweep_prop_configuration',
    builder => '_build_sweep_prop_configuration',
    predicate => 'has_sweep_prop_configuration',
);

sub _build_sweep_prop_configuration {
  my $self = shift;
  my %hash;
  $hash{point_number}=0;
  $hash{number_of_sweep}=0;
  $hash{backwards}=-1;
  $hash{at_end}=-1;
  $hash{at_end_val}=0;
  $hash{save_all}=-1;
  return %hash;
}
```

I am new to Moose and perl in general, excuse me if I missed something in the documentation.

Comment: Class attributes can be defined using [MooseX::ClassAttribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::ClassAttribute). `has` is for instance attributes.

Comment: I imagine `Hash` means "reference to a hash", so `return \%hash`.

Comment: That "solves it". But apparenly Hash is an allowed type and I would like to get an Hash type not an hash ref

Comment: Any string is allowed, but if Moose doesn't know the type, it's up to you to define a class of the given name.

Comment: Re "*I would like to get an Hash type*", That makes no sense. Subs (incl moose accessors) can't return take hashes as parameters, and can't return hashes. They can just take and return scalars. As such, there's no point in having a property that is a hash. (And that's not even factoring that it's impossible to store a hash into an object without using a reference because hashes can only contains scalars.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Moose](https://perldoc.pl/Moose) doesn't define `Hash` as a type (see [Moose::Manual::Types](https://perldoc.pl/Moose::Manual::Types)).

It defines `HashRef`, though. In order to use it, change the builder's last line to

```
return \%hash
```

and change the type constraint to

```
isa => 'HashRef',
```

It still defines an instance attribute, not a class attribute. To define class attributes, use [MooseX::ClassAttribute](https://perldoc.pl/MooseX::ClassAttribute).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how to access it now? ->sweep_prop_configuration(){point_number} does not work...

Comment: `->sweep_prop_configuration->{point_number}`

Comment: Sorry if I ask another followup question, is this way to access by key Moose specific?

Comment: @Indiano: No, that's standard Perl. In fact, more Moosish approach would be to create a class for the configuration so you can't pass invalid fields to the hash.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will read more in to it!

Comment: Hashes are data that can be stored in variables that have a `%` sigil. In most larger applications, you want to store hashes inside of *other* data structures, not just local variables, so hash references are references to hashes that can be stored in `$` variables and basically any storage location (most places in Perl are designed to store scalars and thus can store anything that's `$`-compatible). Same thing with arrays (`@` sigil) and array references (able to be stored pretty much anywhere)